# .map and Foreach loop with RxSwift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, rx-swift

I have a csv file and I am storing into `Sqlite.db`. All is perfectly running in swift. Now I am going to convert `.map and forEach to rxSwift.`

Everytime I am getting an error cannot assign value of type `[CodigoModel]` to `publishSubject`.

I am new to RxSwift not getting an idea.

this is my code:

```
var arrCodigo = PublishSubject<[CodigoModel]>()

self.arrCodigo = arrData.map({ (data) -> CodigoModel in
return CodigoModel.init(data: data)
})
self.arrCodigo.forEach { (obj) in
                        
// store in sqlite db
_ = DBManager.shared.insert(tableName: "codigo_list", dataInDic: [
    "cod_distrito": obj.cod_distrito ?? "",
    "cod_concelho": obj.cod_concelho ?? "",
    "cod_localidade": obj.cod_localidade ?? "",
    "nome_localidade": obj.nome_localidade ?? "",
    "desig_postal": obj.desig_postal ?? ""])
}
```

Comment: Is it `CodigoModel` or `CodingModel`?

Comment: @DanielT. sorry typo mistake its `CodigoModel` I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with RxSwift, but if it is similar to Combine, you are assigning [CodigoModel] to a publisher.

In Combine it would look something like this.

```
var codigoPublisher = PassThroughSubject<[CodingModel]>()

self.arrCodigo = arrData.map({ (data) -> CodigoModel in
return CodigoModel.init(data: data)
})

codigoPublisher.send(self.arrCodigo)
```

you would need to setup a subscriber to receive that value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question. Something like this should work:

```
func example(arrData: [Data]) {
    _ = Observable.from(arrData)
        .map { CodigoModel(data: $0) }
    // assuming you don't want the below on the main thread
        .observe(on: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .subscribe(onNext: { obj in
            _ = DBManager.shared.insert(tableName: "codigo_list", dataInDic: [
                "cod_distrito": obj.cod_distrito ?? "",
                "cod_concelho": obj.cod_concelho ?? "",
                "cod_localidade": obj.cod_localidade ?? "",
                "nome_localidade": obj.nome_localidade ?? "",
                "desig_postal": obj.desig_postal ?? ""])
        })
}
```

No need for a subject here. And since you are learning Rx, remember this quote:

> Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use... Instead of using subjects, favor the factory methods...
> [-- Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com)